# Is this basis of simplex polynomials known?

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-complexes

Put $R_n=\mathbb{R}[t_0,\dotsc,t_n]/(\sum_it_i-1)$ (the ring of polynomial functions on the $n$-simplex).  Consider a monomial $t^a=t_0^{a_0}\dotsb t_n^{a_n}$.  Let $(b_0,\dotsc,b_n)$ be the sequence $(a_0,\dotsc,a_n)$ arranged in nondecreasing order.  I'll say that $t^a$ is *admissible* if $b_n=b_{n-1}+1$.  One can show that the admissible monomials form a basis for $R_n$ with various convenient properties.  In the case $n=1$, you just get the monomials $t_0^{i+1}t_1^i$ and $t_0^it_1^{i+1}$, for example (so $1$ has to be expressed as $t_0+t_1$).  Does this appear in the literature, and if so, under what name?

Comment: Rings of this type, generalized to arbitrary integral polytopes and permitting other coefficients than 1, are considered (at length) in *Positive polynomials and product type actions of compact groups* (AMS Memoirs, 320, 1985) and especially *Positive Polynomials, Convex Integral Polytopes, and a Random Walk Problem* (SLN 1282, 1987), both by me (there are also later publications dealing with them). But they don't address your specific problem.